# How to get entry list of zip file using unzip2 of nodejs

Tags: node.js, zip, unzip

I'm using unzip2 module https://github.com/glebdmitriew/node-unzip-2 to do zip file stream unzipping, but on getting zip entries, I got a problem.

My code is as below:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var entries = [];
var srcStream = fs.createReadStream('test.zip');
srcStream.pipe(unzip.Parse())
.on('entry', function(entry) {
  entries.push(entry.path);
  entry.autodrain();
})
.on('finish', function() {
  console.log(entries);
});
```

But the output is always "[]", it seems when "finish" event got, the operation on "entry" event is not finished.

Is there any solutions that I can get all the entry list?

Comment: Your code works for me. Make sure your zip file is not corrupted.

Comment: @vinayr, You can try some zip file with many small files, using the code, some entries will be lost.

Comment: Use "close" event instead of "finish" can work on some files, but some other zip files may not fire close event.

Answer (score 2):

Use "close" event instead of "finish" may solve this issue.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var entries = [];
var srcStream = fs.createReadStream('test.zip');
srcStream.pipe(unzip.Parse())
.on('entry', function(entry) {
  entries.push(entry.path);
  entry.autodrain();
})
.on('close', function() {
  console.log(entries);
});
```

Comment: Not sure how I would have figured it out without this post, as the documentation is pretty sparse.  Other than the code, is there a better source of info on this module?